# WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW with TransparencyKey causes Win32Exception

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I'm trying to have an empty form window, but using the tool window style. However, calling `Show()` results in the following exception:

> Win32Exception: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> NativeErrorCode: 87
>
> > at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmCreate(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd,
> >     Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Error code 87 is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

```
private class ToolForm : Form {
    public ToolForm() {
        AllowTransparency = true;
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1);
        TransparencyKey = BackColor;
    }

    private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

This works:

```
public class ToolForm : Form {
    public ToolForm() {
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
        this.AllowTransparency = true;
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 1);
        this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is bad code, setting the TransparencyKey property turns on the WS_EX_LAYERED style bit.  You assignment resets it again.  It is not clear why you don't simply use the FormBorderStyle property instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I forgot about that property.

Answer (score 2):

First try using an OR-assignment instead of plain assignment:

```
cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
```

If that doesn't work, you can try additionally OR'ing some of these related styles:

```
cp.ExStyle |= ( int )(
  WS_EX_LAYERED |
  WS_EX_TRANSPARENT |
  WS_EX_NOACTIVATE |
  WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW );
```

The associated values are:

```
WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000,
WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000,
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080,
WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020
```

The `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag may possibly allow the transparency you want without requiring the `TransparencyKey = BackColor;` line.