# C# form upon activating when in minimized state shows incomplete form for few seconds

Tags: c#, winforms

We have a c# form UI issue, when it is minimized state. There are few controls inside the form and the app is brought to normal state from minimized state from a different form - during this transition phase, the UI appears incomplete [image: Incomplete built form UI] for 2-3 seconds and is clearly noticeable one.

we are using  .Activate(); to bring this to normal state. Where we see  black squares are all different controls present in the form. Is there way to avoid this incomplete UI until a complete one is built? Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Something is drastically bogging down the painting of this window.  So you see the unpainted controls, looks black when you use the Opacity or TransparencyKey properties.  Why this code is so slow can never be guessed from a screenshot.

Comment: ... So can you post a cut down snippet of the code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using transparencykey property in your form application, try removing that and try yogi's code.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the following property in your form -

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
   {
       CreateParams objCreateParams = base.CreateParams;
       objCreateParams .ExStyle = 0x02000000;
       return objCreateParams ;
    }
}
```

Using this property, the painting of your controls remains invisible, and will display once it is done with drawing the controls.

Comment: On some windows machines(on win7, win10), adding this causes win32exception while the app is launching. ************** Exception Text **************
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The parameter is incorrect
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.UpdateLayered()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)

Comment: @rajkumaradass - Is it happening on all machines or a particular machine? Probably this might help - http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-flicker-on-windows-forms-applications.aspx OR may be this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033815/ws-ex-toolwindow-with-transparencykey-causes-win32exception